# Python multithreading memory management behave differently for different objects

Tags: python, multithreading, memory, threadpool

I'm using `concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor` to do multithreading tasks. The memory usage is very high and doesn't get released after the job is finished. I use `memory_profiler` to track the memory usage. Here is my test code and output.

```py
import gc
import numpy as np
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
from memory_profiler import profile
import sys
import time

from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

def do():
    a = [1] * (4096*1023)
    return sum(a)

@profile
def main():
    threadpool = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=60)

    tt = time.time()
    jobs = []
    for x in range(1000):
        jobs.append(threadpool.submit(do,))
    rst = [j.result() for j in jobs]
    print(time.time()-tt)
    return None
```

```
Line #    Mem usage    Increment  Occurrences   Line Contents
=============================================================
    18     51.2 MiB     51.2 MiB           1   @profile
    19                                         def main():
    20     51.2 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       threadpool = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=60)
    21                                         
    22     51.2 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       tt = time.time()
    23     51.2 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       jobs = []
    24    404.2 MiB      0.0 MiB        1001       for x in range(1000):
    25    404.2 MiB    353.0 MiB        1000           jobs.append(threadpool.submit(do,))
    26    404.2 MiB      0.0 MiB        1003       rst = [j.result() for j in jobs]
    27    404.2 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       print(time.time()-tt)
    28    404.2 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       return None
```

As showed in the stats, the memory did not get released after the jobs are finished. However, if we change the `do` function into

```py
def do():
    a = [1] * (4096*1024) # <- Increase the size of list a
    return sum(a)
```

The memory will be released correctly. The stats are:

```
Line #    Mem usage    Increment  Occurrences   Line Contents
=============================================================
    18     51.4 MiB     51.4 MiB           1   @profile
    19                                         def main():
    20     51.4 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       threadpool = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=60)
    21                                         
    22     51.4 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       tt = time.time()
    23     51.4 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       jobs = []
    24    116.4 MiB -116311.3 MiB        1001       for x in range(1000):
    25    244.3 MiB -48019.8 MiB        1000           jobs.append(threadpool.submit(do,))
    26     53.5 MiB    -62.9 MiB        1003       rst = [j.result() for j in jobs]
    27     53.5 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       print(time.time()-tt)
    28     53.5 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       return None
```

It seems there is a obj size threshold to control whether the memory will get released. I wonder what's the rule behind this? Also, if I want to make the memory released for all cases, what should I do?

Edit:
About my environment, I'm using a Intel(R) Xeon(R) Platinum 8260 CPU with 16GB RAM, OS is Debian 9 linux 4.14, Python version is 3.8.12, and I'm using Anaconda to manage my Python environment.

Comment: Please provide details about your environment (interpreter, OS, machine, ...)!

Comment: @KlausD. I'm using a Intel(R) Xeon(R) Platinum 8260 CPU with 16GB RAM, OS is Debian 9 linux 4.14, Python version is 3.8.12, and I'm using Anaconda to manage my Python environment.

Comment: This is just a guess but if your *do()* function merely constructs a list that is never used, the Python interpreter could reasonably turn that into a noop. So it may be that it has nothing to do with when the memory is released but is, in fact, never allocated. There's a further clue to what might be going on. On my machine if we do *sum()* in *do()* the duration is ~34s. If I take the *sum()* out it runs in ~13s. Furthermore, if I "watch" the Python process's memory footprint via Activity Monitor (macOS), the usage is very low

Comment: @JCaesar Sorry, I didn't state it clearly. What I mean by "change the do function into a = [1] * (4096*1024)", I didn't mean that I drop "return sum(a)". My point is to change the size of the list a.